# Java foreach with subset of multi-variable array

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible in Java to loop in the **for each statement** to do something similar to this:

```
for(String path: series[634][][3]){
   //DO Something
}
```

I want to specify the first and the last part of this multi-variable array and loop through the middle one.

`series[const1][loopNo][const2]`

Comment: Navigate through the first level of the array, then on the second level.

Comment: What I want is to loop directly in the second level, as I already know the value for the first and the last.

Comment: You cannot do that directly. You would need to do one for per array *dimension*.

Comment: A regular for loop where you only change the middle array's index might be a better idea

Comment: @TimCastelijns, that's what I did. But I am still curious to know if such approach is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-dimensional arrays are just arrays of arrays. You could do this:

```
for(String[][] pathArray1 : series[634]){
   for(String[] pathArray2 : pathArray1){
      String path = pathArray2[3];
      //DO something
   }
}
```

...although this is pretty hackish and ugly, and you should almost definitely use a regular old for loop for this.